# rotateX does not work in IE 11

Tags: internet-explorer, rotation, transform

I have the following structure in my code -

```
<div>
    <table>
        <div className='table-head'>
            <thead>...</thead>
        </div>
        <div className='table-body'>
            <tbody>...</tbody>
        </div>
    </table>
</div>

.table-body {
    transform: rotateX(180deg); // works 
}

.table-body tbody {
    transform: rotateX(180deg); // does not work
}
```

I need to rotate the wrapper around `tbody` first (text gets displayed upside down) to move the scrollbar from bottom to top, then I need to rotate `tbody` again to display the text properly (should only rotate the text not the scrollbar). This works in Chrome but in IE 11 the second `rotateX` is not working. Can someone please explain why?